# Unity - Mismatch between OverlapBox and Gizmo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I want to use OverlapBox to create a box in front of a vehicle and be able to check collision on demand.
I use draw gizmo to be able to see the size and position of the box to confirm that size and position are correct.

This is my code:

```
public class TestCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Collision")]
public Vector3 m_DetectorOffset = Vector3.zero;
public Vector3 m_DetectorSize = Vector3.zero;

private LayerMask m_LayerMask;
private Renderer m_Renderer = null;

void Start()
{
    m_LayerMask = (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Pedestrian")) | (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Vehicle"));

    m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    m_Renderer.material.color = Color.green;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (CheckForCollisions())
        m_Renderer.material.color = Color.red;
    else
        m_Renderer.material.color = Color.green;
}

public bool CheckForCollisions()
{
    Vector3 colliderPos = transform.position + m_DetectorOffset;

    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(colliderPos, m_DetectorSize, transform.rotation, m_LayerMask);

    if (colliders.Length == 1)
    {
        // Ignore collision with itself
        if (colliders[0].gameObject == gameObject)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    if (colliders.Length > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
protected virtual void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(m_DetectorOffset, m_DetectorSize * 2.0f);
}
#endif
}
```

This script works great if I don't rotate the "vehicle" - in the picture the blue cube is the object I want to detect, the green/red cube is the vehicle and the red wireframe box is the OverlapBox represented by the gizmo:
[image]

The issue occurs when the "vehicle" rotates - in the following picture I rotate the vehicle 90 degrees in the Y axis, the gizmo represents the box in the correct position, however the OverlapBox logic is ignoring such rotation (even though when the rotation of the object is passed in the function):
[image]

How can I make the OverlapBox to work properly taking rotation into consideration and being able to represent an accurate gizmo.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue, the problem is the position and rotation of the OverlapBox. I thought the rotation will be applied from the position of the gameobject (which of course it doesn't make any sense), what was happening is that the rotation was applied to the OverlapBox itself.

In my case, since the OverlapBox is only in the front of the vehicle, I replaced the Vector3 offset for a float OffsetZ (only in the Z axis as in the forward of the vehicle), and changed the calculation of the position of the OverlapBox in the CheckForCollisions function as follows:

```
Vector3 colliderPos = transform.position + (transform.forward * m_DetectorOffsetZ);
```

This is the final scrip that makes the OverlapBox work properly and match the respresentation of the gizmo:

```
public class TestCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Collision")]
public Vector3 m_DetectorOffset = Vector3.zero;
public Vector3 m_DetectorSize = Vector3.zero;
public float m_DetectorOffsetZ = 0.0f;

private LayerMask m_LayerMask;
private Renderer m_Renderer = null;

void Start()
{
    m_LayerMask = (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Pedestrian")) | (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Vehicle"));

    m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    m_Renderer.material.color = Color.green;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (CheckForCollisions())
        m_Renderer.material.color = Color.red;
    else
        m_Renderer.material.color = Color.green;
}

public bool CheckForCollisions()
{
    Vector3 colliderPos = transform.position + (transform.forward * m_DetectorOffsetZ);

    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(colliderPos, m_DetectorSize, transform.rotation, m_LayerMask);

    if (colliders.Length == 1)
    {
        // Ignore collision with itself
        if (colliders[0].gameObject == gameObject)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    if (colliders.Length > 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
protected virtual void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
    pos.z = m_DetectorOffsetZ;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(pos, m_DetectorSize * 2.0f);
}
#endif
}
```

Thanks to a reply of xxmariofer in the Unity answer forums, I'll post here just in case the line to use if you want to use a Vector3 as offset instead of a float (for only one axis):

```
Vector3 colliderPos = transform.TransformPoint(m_DetectorOffset);
```

Here is the link to the post:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1757338/mismatch-between-overlapbox-and-gizmo.html

Comment: As alternative to `transform.TransformPoint` which also takes scale into account you could use `transform.position + transform.rotation * m_DetectorOffset;` in case you want to keep the world space scale for the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use collider with `is Trigger = true` flag?
Overlapping is good for rare invoking, but if you want to check every frame you better just use trigger and OnTriggerEnter method.

Comment: If I can't make it work this way then I'll be using OnTriggerEnter / CollisionEnter and so on, however I would like to do a cast on demand (not always I need to be checking for collisions) and then I found on the past that managing multiple entities within colliders can be tedious (you need to keep track of them, if one is disabled instead of leaving does not trigger OnExit, etc... at least that is my experience of a few years ago using colliders).

Comment: Did you try transform.forward? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, I understood the issue, will post my solution